# different Date in java/android

Tags: java, android, date, timezone

When I execute this code in plain java and in android, I get different results:

`System.out.println(new Date(1311940549187l).toString());`

- In plain java, I get this output: `Fri Jul 29 13:55:49 CEST 2011`
- In android, I get this output: `Fri Jul 29 11:55:49 GMT+00:00 2011`

I understand it has something to do with the time zone. But I really need to get the same output. How can I generate a `Date` object based on a `Long` value, and get the same date in both environments ?

---

Edit: I already use SimpleDateFormat and the two datetimes have 2 hours offset. Please tell me how to get rid of the offset.

this is how I use the SimpleDateFormat: `new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The date is the same in both environment, but toString() gives a different result because the two environments are configured with a different timezone.

To format a date for a specific timezone, use a SimpleDateFormat and set the timezone to a specific value (GMT for instance).

UPDATE:

```
TimeZone gmt = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT");
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("...");
format.setCalendar(Calendar.getInstance(gmt));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `SimpleDateFormat` and convert the java code to match the output of what android is giving you.

[SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Or Vice versa (Android convert to match java)

[Android SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: It may be exactly what Maurice said in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
dFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm")
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT:00"); 
dFormat .setTimeZone( tz );
```

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```java
Instant
.ofEpochMilli( 1_311_940_549_187L )
.toString()
```

> 2011-07-29T11:55:49.187Z

## *java.time*

The modern solution uses *java.time* classes. The terrible `java.util.Date` class was replaced by `java.time.Instant`. Both represent a moment as seen in UTC. The `Instant` class is much better behaved in that it **does not inject time zones** in unexpected ways like `Date` does. Never use `java.util.Date`.

Parse your count of milliseconds since epoch reference of first moment of 1970 in UTC as a `java.time.Instant` object.

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( 1_311_940_549_187L ) ;
```

Generate text in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

```
String output = instant.toString() ;
```

> 2011-07-29T11:55:49.187Z

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), a process known as [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

[image: Table of which java.time library to use with which version of Java or Android]